# Find the probability density function of the random variable y=y(x)=x^2 , x with known probability density function.

Tags: statistics, random-variables, density-function

Find the probability density function of the random variable y=y(x)=x^2, x with known probability density function,

$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 &\quad\text{if} \; \infty \lt x \lt -1 \\
       \frac{1}{2}  &\quad\text{if} \; -1 \le x \lt 0 \\
       \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} &\quad\text{if} \; 0 \le x \lt \infty \\ 
     \end{cases}$

I want to use the theorem that says $g(y)=\lvert \frac{dx}{dy} \rvert f(x)$ but since y=x^2 is not bijective I don't know how to proceed. I know that I have to work with $x=-\sqrt{y}$ separately from $x=\sqrt{y}$ but don't know in wich way. Any other method to solve this is fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $f_X$ as a mixture, namely $f_X(x) = f_{X_1}(x) + f_{X_2}(x)$, where $f_{X_1}(x) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbb 1(-1 \le x < 0)$ and $f_{X_2}(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x} \mathbb 1 (x \ge 0)$.  Then the transformed density is $$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}\left( f_{X_1}(-\sqrt{y}) + f_{X_2}(\sqrt{y})\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \mathbb 1 (0 < y \le 1) + \frac{1}{2} e^{-\sqrt{y}} \mathbb 1 (y \ge 0) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{y}} \begin{cases} 1 + e^{-\sqrt{y}} , & 0 \le y \le 1 \\ e^{-\sqrt{y}}, & 1 < y < \infty. \end{cases}
\end{align}$$
This approach works because $f_X$ is a mixture of two densities for which the transformation $Y = X^2$ is monotone on their individual supports.

Comment: shouldn't it be $f_{X_{1}}(-\sqrt{y})$ instead of $f_{X_{1}}(\sqrt{y})$ ?

Comment: @Karl Yes, you are correct; thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the CDF of $Y$ and differentiating. Note that for $y \ge 0$ we have $P(Y \le y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \le X \le \sqrt{y})$.

Comment: Is it ok to then say that $P(Y \le y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \le X \le \sqrt{y}) = P(-\sqrt{y} \le X \lt 0 \; U \; 0 \le X \le \sqrt{y})$ ? so I can do the sum of the probabilities ?

Comment: @Karl Yes, that's fine. You are essentially breaking up an integral $\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}}$ into $\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^0 + \int_0^{\sqrt{y}}$.

Comment: Right, the problem doing the integral is that I think I mess up the intervals, since $y \ge 0$ but I get intervals where y is negative.